# Как правильно наследовать сущность в symfony?

Tags: php, orm, symfony2, doctrine

Как правильно наследовать сущность от другой сущности?
У меня есть абстрактная сущность **AbstractPerson** в которой есть определенные свойства, есть сущность **Person**(пустой объект без свойств) которая наследует **AbstractPerson**.
Мы наполняем **Person** и в итоге получаем объект **Person** с заполненными свойствами **AbstractPerson** в дебаггере выглядит примерно так:

```
AppBundle\Entity\Person(переменная $owner) -> *AbstractPerson*id=null
                                           -> *AbstractPerson*type='my_type'
```

Когда объект **AbstractPerson** был просто сущностью(**не абстрактной**), то в таком случае объект был равен `null`(даже когда свойство **type** заполнено)

```
AppBundle\Entity\AbstractPerson(переменная $owner) -> null
```

В чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Исходя из Вашего вопроса могу предположить, что вы вызвали конструктор для класса Person и полученный объект записали в переменную $owner. Переменная $owner теперь содержит объект класса Person и соответственно все поля которые были заполненны или объявлены по дефолту.

Класс AbstractPerson - это абстрактный и обявлен с использованием ключевого слова abstract. Конструктор такого класса невозможно вызвать поскольку это приведет к ошибке.

Нельзя создавать объекты абстрактных классов, они задуманы как шаблоны для наследования.

Поскольку объект не был создан то переменная  $owner равна null.
Подробнее можете прочитать здесь http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.php